# How to count the number of items in a group after using Groupby in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have multiple columns in my dataframe of which I am using 2 columns "customer id" and "trip id". I used the groupby function `data.groupby(['customer_id','trip_id'])` There are multiple trips taken from each customer. I want to count how many trips each customer took, but when I am using aggregate function along with group by I am getting 1 in all the rows. How should I proceed ? 
I want something in this format.

```
Example : 
Customer_id , Trip_Id, Count
CustID1 ,trip1, 3 
        trip 2
        trip 3
CustID2 ,Trip450, 2
         Trip23
```

Answer (score 2):

You can group by customer and count the number of unique trips using the built in nunique:

```
data.groupby('Customer_id').agg(Count=('Trip_id', 'nunique'))
```

Comment: Sure! Can you consider accepting the answer? Or anything you would like for me to improve in the answer?

Answer (score -1):

You can use `data.groupby('customer_id','trip_id').count()`

Example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=["c1","c1a","c1b"], data = [[1,2,3],[1,5,6],[2,8,9]])
print(df1)

# | c1 | c1a | c1b |
# |----|-----|-----|
# | x  | 2   | 3   |
# | z  | 5   | 6   |
# | z  | 8   | 9   |

df2 = df1.groupby("c1").count()
print(df2)

# |    | c1a | c1b |
# |----|-----|-----|
# | x  | 1   | 1   |
# | z  | 2   | 2   |
```

Comment: That works too! But if for some reason you have the same trip_id twice for a customer it will fail because it counts the number of occurrences not the number of unique trip ids, just make sure you drop duplicates when using this